# Python: Export all used modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-3.4

I'm using a lot of modules installed by Internet.

It's possible to write a script to copy automatically all of these module in a folder?
I don't know where these modules are, I only write:

```
  import module1
  import module2
```

I simply want that **module1** and **module2** can copied in a folder in order to use my **file.py** in other pc witouth installing any software except for Python.

Answer (score 0):

pip and virtualenvs. You develop locally on a virtualenv, installing and uninstalling whatever you want. When your code is exportable make a list of requirements with command "pip freeze". Then you carry your code to another computer, without any other code except for the output of "pip freeze" in a file called "requirements.txt". Do a "pip install -r requirements.txt" and... ¡magic! All are installed in their proper path.

If you are interested in where those modules are, find your python path and find a "site-packages" folder (on Windows it usually is "C:\PythonX.X\lib\site-packages" or something like that). But I'm 100% sure you will regret copying modules manually from here to there.